# Extending tt_content with inline element, element is not attached

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I created an extension in TYPO3 9.5 for adding multiple elements from another table to tt_content with type "inline" (IRRE) according to the [tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/irre_tutorial/Manual/Index.html#normalized-data-structure-for-1-n-relations).

I can add new inline elements to a content element in backend but as I am saving them, they are not attached to the tt_content element. But I can see them as records in the list view. Only the connection between the two elements are missing.

The definition of the additional field for tt_content:

```
CREATE TABLE tt_content (
    tx_jrinterview_question_answer int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
);
```

The definition of the new records table:

```
CREATE TABLE tx_jrinterview_question_answer (
    parentid  int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    parenttable varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    question varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    answer text
);
```

The TCA part for tt_content to add the IRRE functionality:

```
'tx_jrinterview_question_answer' => [
    'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'Questions and Answers',
        'config' => [
             'type' => 'inline',
             'allowed' => 'tx_jrinterview_question_answer',
             'foreign_table' => 'tx_jrinterview_question_answer',
             'foreign_field' => 'parentid',
             'foreign_table_field' => 'parenttable',
             'minitems' => 0,
             'maxitems' => 99,
         ],
     ],
],
```

And the TCA for the new record:

```
<?php
return [
    'ctrl' => [
        'title' => 'Question and answer',
        'label' => 'question',
        'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
        'crdate' => 'crdate',
        'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
        'versioningWS' => true,
        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
        'transOrigDiffSourceField' => 'l10n_diffsource',
        'delete' => 'deleted',
        'enablecolumns' => [
            'disabled' => 'hidden',
            'starttime' => 'starttime',
            'endtime' => 'endtime',
        ],
        'searchFields' => 'question,answer',
    ],
    'interface' => [
        'showRecordFieldList' => 'parentid,parenttable,sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden, question, answer',
    ],
    'types' => [
        '0' => ['showitem' => 'parentid, parenttable, sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden, question, answer, --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access, starttime, endtime'],
    ],
    'columns' => [
        'pid' => [
            'label' => 'Pid',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough'
            ]
        ],
        'crdate' => [
            'label' => 'Crdate',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ]
        ],
        'tstamp' => [
            'label' => 'Tstamp',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ]
        ],
        'sys_language_uid' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.language',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'special' => 'languages',
                'items' => [
                    [
                        'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.allLanguages',
                        -1,
                        'flags-multiple'
                    ]
                ],
                'default' => 0,
            ],
        ],
        'l10n_parent' => [
            'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:>:0',
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.l18n_parent',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'default' => 0,
                'items' => [
                    ['', 0],
                ],
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_jrinterview_question_answer',
                'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tx_jrinterview_question_answer.pid=###CURRENT_PID### AND tx_jrinterview_question_answer.sys_language_uid IN (-1,0)',
            ],
        ],
        'l10n_diffsource' => [
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ],
        ],
        't3ver_label' => [
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.versionLabel',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'max' => 255,
            ],
        ],
        'hidden' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.hidden',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'check',
                'items' => [
                    '1' => [
                        '0' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_core.xlf:labels.enabled'
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'starttime' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'behaviour' => [
                'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true
            ],
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.starttime',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
                'size' => 13,
                'eval' => 'datetime',
                'default' => 0,
            ],
        ],
        'endtime' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'behaviour' => [
                'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true
            ],
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.endtime',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
                'size' => 13,
                'eval' => 'datetime',
                'default' => 0,
                'range' => [
                    'upper' => mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2038)
                ],
            ],
        ],

        'parentid' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'parentid',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ],
        ],
        'parenttable' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'parenttable',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ],
        ],
        'question' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'question',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ],
        ],
        'answer' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'answer',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'cols' => 40,
                'rows' => 15,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ]
        ],

    ],
];
```

Perhaps this has to be something with the language? If I change in the table directly the parentid and parenttable after creating it via IRRE, the record is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Add more fields to your question/answer table.
In your ext_tables.sql

```
CREATE TABLE tx_jrinterview_question_answer (
    uid int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    pid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    tstamp int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    crdate int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    cruser_id int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    deleted tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    hidden tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

    parentid  int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    parenttable varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    question varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    answer text,

    PRIMARY KEY (uid),
    KEY parent (pid)
);
```

In your Configuration/TCA/tx_jrinterview_question_answer.php

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();

return [
    'ctrl' => [
        'title' => 'tx_jrinterview_question_answer',
        'label' => 'question',
        'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
        'crdate' => 'crdate',
        'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
        'delete' => 'deleted',
        'enablecolumns' => [
            'disabled' => 'hidden',
        ],
    ],
    'interface' => [
        'showRecordFieldList' => 'parentid,parenttable,question,answer'
    ],
    'columns' => [
        'pid' => [
            'label' => 'Pid',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough'
            ]
        ],
        'crdate' => [
            'label' => 'Crdate',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ]
        ],
        'tstamp' => [
            'label' => 'Tstamp',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ]
        ],
        'hidden' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'Hidden',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'check',
                'default' => 0
            ]
        ],
        'parentid' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'Parentid',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ],
        ],
        'parenttable' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'Parenttable',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ],
        ],
        'question' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'Question',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ],
        ],
        'answer' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'Answer',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'cols' => 40,
                'rows' => 15,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ]
        ],
    ],
    'types' => [
        0 => [
            'showitem' => 'parentid,parenttable,question,answer'
        ]
    ]
];
```

And the connection should be keept. I did test it.

Comment: I added now the full TCA into my question and edded the pid, crdate, tstamp columns with type `passthrough` - but the same effect, no assignment to the tt_content element.